# RDLC Report showing #Error value in report

Tags: rdlc

I am using this Expression for Closing Balance

(Fields!Oct_Op.Value + Reportitems!OctsmRV.Value + Reportitems!OctsmRT.Value) - (Reportitems!OctsmPay.Value +Reportitems!OctsmOpay.Value)

But it is showing #Error value in report.

Thank you

Comment: Are there any messages in Output window (provided that you are developing in VS)? Are all the values supplied and are numeric?

Comment: Force each value to convert in it's type, That is if all are Int then use `CInt` and so on.